# Agora.io - How to share video timestamps using mediaPlayer? - iOS

Tags: swift, video, media-player, agora.io

Here's what I'm trying to do: Using Agora.io's MediaPlayer API, I want to be able to publish video to a channel (which I can do using RtcChannelPublishPlugin), but I need to be able to then *receive* the media's current timestamp on the non-publishing device. Then, I will be able to "re-publish" the video from the other user starting at the same timestamp.

I've tried using AgoraRtm, but I don't think messages sent using rtm can be saved as variables.
I've found a way to get the timestamp and print it out, but the trouble is getting it to the other users in the channel and using it as a variable.

Has anyone experienced something like this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I'm using Agora's API example project as a base.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of meta data that goes with the video stream. See the following API:
https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/oc/Classes/AgoraRtcEngineKit.html#//api/name/setMediaMetadataDataSource:withType: